# Form based authentication: renaming <form-login-page>

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml

I have a question about Securing web applications using form-based authentication.
I want the file web.xml to link to the following page when I run the application:

```
<form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
```

It seems like web.xml uses the following link by default:

```
<form-login-page>/index.jsp</form-login-page>
```

My question is: How can I change this? The file web.xml looks as follows:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>SecureServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>SecureServlet</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>SecureServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/SecureServlet</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <session-config>
            <session-timeout>
                30
            </session-timeout>
        </session-config>
        <security-constraint>
            <display-name>Admin Pages</display-name>
            <web-resource-collection>
                <web-resource-name>Administrative Pages</web-resource-name>
                <description/>
                <url-pattern>/admin.jsp</url-pattern>
            </web-resource-collection>
            <auth-constraint>
                <role-name>admin</role-name>
            </auth-constraint>
            <user-data-constraint>
                <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
            </user-data-constraint>
        </security-constraint>
        <login-config>
            <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
            <realm-name>file</realm-name>
            <form-login-config>
                <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
                <form-error-page>/errorpage.jsp</form-error-page>
            </form-login-config>
        </login-config>
        <security-role>
            <description>Administrator</description>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </security-role>
        <security-role>
            <description>User</description>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </security-role>
    </web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the welcome file in your web.xml to set the default location for your context root to be your login page: -

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Note that the file is relative to the context root so no preceding slash is required.

Comment: I have a file admin.jsp which needs to be shown when the correct username and password are entered. When I try this, I get redirected back to index.jsp. Do you know the solution for this problem?

Comment: How did you try to redirect after login?

Comment: I think you want to set your welcome file to `admin.jsp` actually. This will cause the security directive to redirect you to the login page when you aren't authenticated, when you authenticate it will send you to the original URL you requested, i.e., `admin.jsp`.

Comment: I tried to set the welcome file to admin.jsp, but then I'm getting the admin page without logging in.

Comment: Weird, must be something wrong with the security constraint. Otherwise someone could just type in the URL without logging in! Let me check to see if it's something obvious.

Comment: Are you sure that `/context-root/admin.jsp` will match and it isn't something like `/context-root/secure/admin.jsp`

Comment: When I'm placing the <welcome-file-list> tags inside the <security-constraint> tags I'm getting the error SEVERE: Exception while deploying the app [securewebapp] : Invalid URL Pattern: [http://localhost/securewebapp/admin/admin.jsp] and the application will not build.

Comment: I have no secure folder, and context-root is my securewebapp folder

Comment: Ok, well, the `welcome-file-list` should come under the `webapp` element and not the security element. I suggest trying to get it to re-direct to the login page when you request admin.jsp directly. If you still can't get it working after that then please come back and ask some more questions.

Comment: You should make your url pattern like this `<url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>` if all your admin pages are under an admin folder.